# Count # of items in each section for a column and execute a formula and then cycle through the next section

Tags: excel, vba

I have been brainstorming for quite a while and am struggling on a good starting point for the following code I would like to write.  The spreadsheet I'm working on will have several sections broken out with different invoice detail that begins with "Stock No/SKU" in the spreadsheet example I've entered below.  I would like to create a Macro that will look through each occurence/section:

1. Count the number of rows or items that are in between the "Stock No/SKU" and "SUBTOTAL"
2. If the # of rows is >1 then I would like to divide the Tax amount by the Subtotal amount {tax amount and subtotal amount will be shown in column B next to their field in column A}
3. Then I would like create a new total (which is not shown) for each item by multiplying the sales tax % calculated in #2 and the item total several columns over (not shown in the spreadsheet example below)
4. Then I would like the macro to proceed to the next section where it finds "Stock No/SKU" and repeat the steps.  If the section only contains one item then I would like for it to skip the steps and Find the next "Stock No/SKU" to evaluate and so on until the last one is found.

I've have been playing around with this code to try to get me somewhere but by all means it is not the finished product.  If anyone has any good ideas on where to begin I will be very appreciative.  I will run with it and see how far I can go as I'm always trying to expand my knowledge and creative techniques.

```
Revised Code based off of answer:
Sub stax()    
Dim Wk4 As Worksheet
Set Wk4 = Sheets("Open Invoice List")

Dim r As Range
Dim start As Integer
Dim rws As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim isItem As Boolean


Set r = Wk4.Range("A1")
start = r.Row
rws = Wk4.UsedRange.Rows.Count

'loop
For i = start To rws
    Select Case r
        Case "Stock No/SKU"
            isItem = True
            r.Offset(0, 1).End(xlDown).Offset(-2, 1).Formula = r.Offset(0, 1).End(xlDown).Offset(-2, 0) / r.Offset(0, 1).End(xlDown).Offset(-3, 0)

        Case "SUBTOTAL:"
            isItem = False
            r.Offset(1, 2).Font.Color = vbBlue


        Case Else
        'do something to the selection in between
            If isItem Then r.Offset(0, 9).Formula = Round(r.Offset(0, 5) * r.Offset(0, 1).End(xlDown).Offset(-2, 1), 2) + r.Offset(0, 5)



    End Select

    'Move to next row
    Set r = r.Offset(1, 0)

Next i



'Cleanup
Set r = Nothing
Set Wk4 = Nothing
    End Sub
```

Spreadsheet example:

```
Let's say starting at Row9 in Column A

Stock No/SKU
item1
SUBTOTAL:
TAX

{several rows in between}

Stock No/SKU
item1
item2
item3
item4
SUBTOTAL:
TAX

{several rows in between}

Stock No/SKU
item1
item2
SUBTOTAL:
TAX
```

Comment: Define a Range r. Set r to A9. Create a loop which breaks on r.Row = Sheets(1).UdesRange.Rows.Count. If r is "Stock..." set a counter to 0 and a flag to true. Increment counter while you have items (i.e. not hit SUBTOTAL). Sum up the Items worth. When r = SUBTOTAL set flag to false and do your calculations.

Comment: I had difficulty with the counter since I had never set one up but I did come up with this revised code.  Just as a test it currently selects the items between "Stock No/SKU" and "SUBTOTAL:" and changes the font to blue.  My problem now is how I can get it to proceed to the next section and do the same procedure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Do-While Loop only runs up to the Break condition, in your case foundStock. You can't use this here since you would have to restart it over and over with that condition. It is therefore the wrong kind of loop (or condition).

You have to loop all the way to the bottom of your list. You can use UsedRange to get the number of rows used in your Worksheet and use this as a point of terminating a simple From To.

Try this (untested):

```
Dim sh as Worksheet
Dim r as Range
Dim start as Integer, rws as Integer, i as Integer
Dim isItem as Boolean

'Presets
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Open Invoice List")
Set r = sh.Range("A9")    
start = r.Row
rws = sh.UsedRange.Rows.Count

'Loop
For i = start to rws

    Select Case r

        Case "Stock No/SKU"
            isItem = true

        Case "SUBTOTAL:" 
            isItem = false
            r.Offset(0,1).Font.Color = vbRed

        Case Else
            If isItem then r.Offset(0,1).Font.Color = vbBlue

    End Select

    'Move to next row
    Set r = r.Offset(1,0)

Next i

'Cleanup
Set r = Nothing
Set sh = Nothing
```

Comment: Thanks.  Your layout out helped me tremendously and I did learn quite a bit.  I edited my original question with the code I used to calculate the sales tax and add it to the total for each item plus the sales tax in several columns to the right.

Comment: I have been spending most of trying to figure out how I can take all the "isItem" and paste it on a different worksheet within the same workbook.  It currently cycles through each "r" under isItem and pastes it in the destination overwriting the previous cell.  I want to collect all the "r's" for a given column and paste it in the other worksheet.  I've tried looping, setting ranges, for each, etc. but I'm missing something in my logic.  Any ideas.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Here is that code to select all the items and paste it on a new worksheet.  Let me know your thoughts.

```
Sub populatetemplate()

Dim Wk4 As Worksheet
Set Wk4 = Sheets("Open Invoice List")

Dim Wk1 As Worksheet
Set Wk1 = Sheets("Form")


Dim r As Range
Dim start As Integer
Dim rws As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim isItem As Boolean


Set r = Wk4.Range("A1")
start = r.Row
rws = Wk4.UsedRange.Rows.Count


Dim p As Integer
p = 17

'loop
For i = start To rws
    Select Case r
        Case "Stock No/SKU"
            isItem = True

        Case "SUBTOTAL:"
            isItem = False

        Case Else
        'do something to the selection in between
        If isItem Then
            With r.Offset(0, 1)
            Wk1.Cells(p, 9).Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count).Value = .Value
            p = p + 1
            End With
        End If


    End Select

    'Move to next row
    Set r = r.Offset(1, 0)

Next i



'Cleanup
Set r = Nothing
Set Wk4 = Nothing


End Sub
```